# How to detect whether Vimeo player was paused by user OR by scrolling out of viewport

Tags: javascript, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have a single video on a website that automatically plays when it scrolls into the viewport and pauses when it leaves the viewport. The video is muted so that it also works on mobile.

I'm using the Vimeo API to play and pause the video, and some JS to detect, on both load and when scrolling, whether the video is within the viewport.

This all works great, except that the user has the option to manually pause the video via the usual Vimeo playbar, as well as turn up the volume (the video's music soundtrack isn't essential for watching it, but some users might want to hear it).

The problem is that if the user manually pauses the video, and then starts scrolling, the script detects that the video is in viewport and starts playing it again, at least until the video has left the viewport.

This is not desirable, and it's especially undesirable if the user has turned up the volume and then paused the video, because now suddenly they will hear the video playing as they start scrolling down.

Is there a way to detect whether a user has interacted with the Vimeo player (to pause it) vs. when it's automatically paused from scrolling out of the viewport? I didn't see it when looking through the Vimeo API documentation (https://github.com/vimeo/player.js).

If that's possible, then I would simply add a conditional statement that says not to play the video when scrolled within viewport if it's currently paused by the user.

Or perhaps there's some other way to address? The only other requirement is that the solution be pure/vanilla JS.

Current code:

```
<div id="video-box">
  <iframe id="i_video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/123456789?loop=1&amp;muted=1&amp;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" width="530" height="298" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>

<script>
  var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
  var player = new Vimeo.Player(iframe);

  function vimeoPlay(){
    player.play()
  };

  function vimeoPause(){
    player.pause()
  };

  var dv = document.getElementById('video-box');
  var v = document.getElementById('i_video');

  function isAnyPartOfElementInViewport(dv) {
    const rect = dv.getBoundingClientRect();
    const windowHeight = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
    const windowWidth = (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth);
    const vertInView = (rect.top <= windowHeight) && ((rect.top + rect.height) >= 0);
    const horInView = (rect.left <= windowWidth) && ((rect.left + rect.width) >= 0);

    return (vertInView && horInView);
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    if (isAnyPartOfElementInViewport(dv)) {
      vimeoPlay();
    }
    else {
      vimeoPause();
    }
  }, false);

  window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {

  if (isAnyPartOfElementInViewport(dv)) {
    vimeoPlay();
  }
  else {
    vimeoPause();
  }
  }, false);
  </script>
```

**11/15/18 Edited to Add:**

Inside if

```
(isAnyPartOfElementInViewport(dv)) {,
```

there is currently just

```
vimeoPlay(),
```

which means when in the viewport, no matter whether the user manually clicked pause on the Vimeo player, as soon as they start scrolling the video will play again.

What would you suggest for an inner conditional statement to place around vimeoPlay() such that it only plays if the user hasn't manually paused the player?

I can't just check to see if the video is paused using the API's getPaused() because I don't believe that distinguishes between whether it was paused automatically due to it being out of viewport or manually by clicking the pause button.

I guess if there were a way to ask "was this video paused while in viewport" and then only play the video if that condition is NOT true, that might help, but I'm not sure how to write that.

Comment: I guess, `vimeoPause()` indicates the user has interacted with pause activity and in here, `if (isAnyPartOfElementInViewport(dv)) {` indicates the user is scrolling page! This is how you can detect.

Comment: @varit05: Thanks, but I don't think that allows me to detect whether the pause was due to the user clicking the pause button or because of being out of viewport, or perhaps I'm misunderstanding your comment. See the edit I made to my question for more on this.

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution,

When User is paused the video, as per the Vimeo github [docs](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js)

> When a video is paused by User!.

Solution: Add this to your JS file

```
player.on('pause', function() {
    console.log('paused the User!');
});
```

> When a video is paused by scrolling

Solution:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {

    if (isAnyPartOfElementInViewport(dv)) {
        vimeoPlay();
    } else {
        console.log('paused by scrolling');
        vimeoPause();
    }
}, false);
```

> Update: Attached Updated fiddler

Here is the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/varit05/foq92ktw/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! However, I don't think that solved the issue. In your fiddle, if I press the pause button on the video and then scroll down a bit, the video starts playing again (due to the part of the JS that plays the video whenever in viewport). How might you adjust the code to prevent vimeoPlay() from firing when in the viewport **IF** the user manually pressed pause, so that the video the user manually paused remains paused when scrolled?

Comment: @MaryJames Here is the update Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/varit05/foq92ktw/ Please check

Comment: Thank you again! That definitely did the trick of keeping the video paused while in the viewport (after the user manually pauses it), but if scrolled out of viewport and then back into viewport, it starts playing again. I'm trying to build on your code additions to keep a user-paused video in the pause state at all times until the user manually plays it again. Essentially, when user-paused, isAnyPartOfElementInViewport should not determine whether to unpause the video. I'm struggling, however. Any additional thoughts?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your question. For additional part, you can build a logic in paused function and can give it a try. I will check and come back to you as soon as possible.